# Get local time in timezone (looking for space optimized library/method)

Tags: javascript, angular

**Edited** to make the ask more specific - see comments below

I am using [libphonenumber](https://github.com/catamphetamine/libphonenumber-js) to try and parse phone numbers in my address book. If it is successful in parsing, it returns a two letter country code, like `US` (USA), `SE` (Sweden), `IN` (India) etc. Let's assume I do further processing to convert this to a city (based on prefix), so I get `America/New_York` etc. I am ok with this part being a "best guess" for now.

I am interested in showing the current local time in these countries (I am writing a [calling card app](https://github.com/pliablepixels/cardCall) in Angular/Ionic where I want to display local time in countries so people can be conscious of timezone before hitting 'dial')

I'd like to request your opinion on how to do this:

- Ideally, I'd like a *small* javascript library that *only* does local time given a country code. I haven't found one yet. I am aware of [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-formats/) but its not small. It pulls in other deps. See [here](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/356).
- If that is not possible, an external API is also a possibility, but needs to be free (rate limit is ok). Google Timezone doesn't seem to be suited for what I need.

Would appreciate your inputs. Thanks.

Comment: What time is it right now in `US`? There's multiple zones.

Comment: Agreed, there are more countries that have multiple time zones. Your request to map 1 country to 1 timezone is therefore not a bijection. Either change the request or the fact there is 1 result.

Comment: True. I've updated the ask.

Comment: @user1361529 add your code what you have tried?

Comment: I dunno, [25kb in the *largest* variation](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) seems reasonably small to me vs. the headache of reinventing this wheel…

Comment: @VicJordan, its easy with moment-timezone `moment().tz("Europe/London")`. My ask if for an alternate method/compact library

Comment: @deceze thanks - my understanding is its much larger https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/356

Comment: @user1361529 Don't jump into conclusions, [check it](https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js) yourself. It's 25k minified and gzipped, 180k minified. The issue you're citing also explains why it may seem larger https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/356#issuecomment-225258637 . The thing you're requesting cannot be *small* - because it should contain TZ data. There's no single TZ for US and many other countries. Considering that you will likely need Moment for date manipulation in real world app any way, it looks like a good deal.

Comment: You can check the alternatives by yourself https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=timezone&ref=opensearch&type=Repositories . That's why asking for libraries is considered off-topic on SO. Most times the answer boils down to picking most starred libs from Github (and they are not necessarily well-maintained when a reader checks them), also a honey pot for maintainers to promote their libs.